# Sql call timeout - Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I get this error:

```
The wait operation timed out
```

And it occurs on this line:

```
da.Fill(result);
```

On the following code:

```
public static DataTable Get_Table_Grouped()
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["My_Data"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
        SELECT TOP 10  Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute4, Attribute5, 
        Sum([Attribute6]) As Attribute6
        FROM My_Table
        group by Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute4, Attribute5", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(result);
            con.Close();
            da.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The following is my connection string for "My_Data"

```
<add name="My_Data" connectionString="Data Source=Database_Location;User ID=username;Password=my_password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

What can I do to fix this? Is there a way to stop the timeout? When I try the same query directly in Microsoft SQL Server it works but after a while, I don't see anything in my code that causes the timeout

Answer (score 1):

A timeout error means that the query took longer than the maximum time you defined. You need to improve the query, change the timeout value or check if there any locks on the table.

You can change the timeout value by doing this:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

You can also specify the timeout value in the connection string by adding Connection Timeout=600 at the end. In your case:

```
Data Source=Database_Location;User ID=username;Password=my_password;Connection Timeout=600;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for a command timeout is `30 seconds`. If your query is pulling in a massive amount of data, or is slow, you'll have to manually set the timeout value. Francisco offered a couple possibilities, but another way you can increase the timeout is through your `SqlDataAdapter` instance:

```
da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = MyIntValue;
```

Also, since you're calling your `SqlConnection` with a `using` statement, your `con.Close()` is actually redundant.